# How to implement masonry layout as an android custom list?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have face problem to add android `masonry` custom list with dynamic view and what are the right steps for using this. Please give me the best solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: explain in detail? what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should be talking about the GridLayout.

Take a look at the Developers Blog post about it http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html

The API is in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html